# Rethinkdb Node.JS .changes() unwanted looping

Tags: node.js, socket.io, rethinkdb

i have a a problem with Node JS, and rethinkdb module.
I'm currently developing program for my thesis

this pieces code of `db.js`:

```
var r = require("rethinkdb"); 
var host = "localhost";
var db = "example";
var port = 28015;
class dbs{
    connectToDb(callback){
        r.connect({
        host:host,
        port:port,
        db:db
        },function(err,connection){
             return callback(err,connection);
          });
    }

  streamAllData(tableName,callback){
  this.connectToDb(function(err,conn){
    r.table(tableName).changes().run(conn,function(err,cursor){
      if(err){
        return callback(true,err);
      }
      else{
        cursor.next(function(err,rows){
          return callback(null,rows);
        });

      }
    });
  });
}
}
```

and this pieces of code from `server.js`

```
var dbrs = require("./db");
var rdb = new dbrs();
var io = require("socket.io").listen(https.createServer(options,app).listen(port));
io.on("connection",function(socket){
   rdb.streamAllData("userlocation",function(err,data){
      socket.emit("broadcast:userlocation",data);
   });
});
```

that result is always sending 7 same data . actually mobile phone sending cordinates to server is clean with configured interval.

this unwanted looping is always crashed my browser when im trying to draw driver location to maps.

[image]

that is a screenshot from chrome console

Answer (score 1):

You method name `streamAllData` does not match your usage of `cursor.next`, which only fetches a single result. Perhaps you meant to use `cursor.each` instead?

See https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/next/

Comment: of course . cause i need a single result every changed row then i process every single row .